# Override \centering to left justify an image

Tags: graphics, horizontal-alignment, algorithms

### Background

Dozens of source code snippets inserted into a document as images inside of Algorithm floats. Other images are screen captures, inserted as Graphics floats, to make a distinction. All Graphic floats should be centred, thus the preamble contains:

```
% Resize figures that are too wide for the page.
\let\oldincludegraphics\includegraphics
\renewcommand\includegraphics[2][]{%
  \oldincludegraphics[width=\ScaleIfNeeded]{#2}
  \centering
}
```

This works, as `ScaleIfNeeded` is defined elsewhere, resulting in all images being centred, including the Algorithm images.

### Problem

The Algorithm floats also contain images, and these images are centred, which is undesirable. The code for each Algorithm resembles:

```
\begin{algorithm}[H]
\includegraphics{source/sql/query-formatted.sql.png}
\caption{\label{alg:Query-with-Formatting}Query with Formatting}
\end{algorithm}
```

### Ideas

Tried:

```
% Centre algorithms.
\let\oldalgorithm\algorithm
\let\endoldalgorithm\endalgorithm
\renewenvironment{algorithm}[1][ht]{%
  \begin{flushleft}
  \oldalgorithm[#1]
  \end{flushleft}
  }%
  {\endoldalgorithm}
```

This results in a number of errors ("Missing `}` inserted", amongst others).

### Question

How can images embedded exclusively within Algorithm floats be left-justified?

### Bonus Question

How can a thick, left-hand vertical rule (or any stylistic change) be made to the Algorithm floats? For example, the left-hand border on the "batch source text" from this [indirectly-related question](https://superuser.com/questions/213217/convert-html-to-image/213331#213331). (Or any source code snippets on SuperUser.com, for that matter.)

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is untested, but how about something like the following?

```
\expandafter\def\expandafter\algorithm\expandafter{%
        \expandafter\let\expandafter\centering\expandafter\relax
        \algorithm
}
```

This makes `\centering` do nothing in the algorithm environment. (There's actually a better way to do such things with the `etoolbox` package.) If you want, you could replace `\relax` with `\raggedright` (or better `\RaggedRight` from the `ragged2e` package) if you really want that behavior. The `flushleft` environment is not what you want since that's going to add extra space.

**Edit:**
Actually, I've got a better idea than redefining `\centering` locally which just feels wrong. How about this:

```
\let\oldincludegraphics\includegraphics[2][]{%
        \oldincludegraphics[width=\ScaleIfNeeded]{#2}%
        \graphicsalignment
}
\expandafter\def\expandafter\algorithm\expandafter{%
        \expandafter\let\expandafter\graphicsalignment\expandafter\relax
        \algorithm
}
\let\graphicsalignment\centering
```

**Bonus Question:**
Here's one idea for getting a rule.

```
\newdimen\coderulewidth \coderulewidth=1em
\newdimen\coderulesep \coderulesep=1em
\newdimen\coderuleseptemp
\newbox\codebox
\newenvironment{coderule}[1][\coderulesep]{%
        \par
        \coderuleseptemp=#1\relax
        \setbox\codebox=\vbox\bgroup
                \linewidth=\dimexpr\linewidth-\coderulewidth-\coderulesep\relax
                \hsize=\linewidth
}{%
        \egroup
        \noindent
        \strut
        \hbox{%
                \vrule width\coderulewidth
                \kern\coderuleseptemp
                \box\codebox
        }%
}
```

As an example of usage, here are a few grafs with the thick rule on the left (this example needs the `lipsum` package).

```
\begin{coderule}
\lipsum[1-2]
\end{coderule}
```

For an `algorithmic`, the algorithm is already indented, so you can use the optional argument (or just redefine `\coderulesep`).

```
\begin{algorithm}
\begin{coderule}[0pt]
\begin{algorithmic}
\STATE $x\gets0$
\STATE $y\gets1$
\STATE $z\gets x+y$
\end{algorithmic}
\end{coderule}
\end{algorithm}
```

Comment: @TH.: The revised version is brilliant. Am learning a lot from you LaTeX wizards. Thank you for the bonus answer, too.

Comment: @TH.: For the bonus question, I should have mentioned that I'm using LyX, so adding code to each Algorithm float manually is not an option. Am going to try and make the `coderulesep` automatically apply. Thanks!

Comment: @TH.: Almost have the vertical rule working by coding `\vrule width 1em` to the `\expandafter` section. The `\vrule` is split from the image with `[H]`.

Comment: @Dave: One idea would be to save `\algorithm` and `\endalgorithm` as before and then use `\renewenvironment` to capture the contents of the algorithm in a `\vbox` as I did in `coderule`. Then, after the `\egroup` which ends the `\vbox`, use the saved `\algorithm` and `\endalgorithm` along with the rule and the box. (I don't use LyX though so I'm not really sure what you can and cannot do.)

Comment: @Dave: Oh, sorry. I forgot context. I deleted that other comment.