# Left-hand vertical rule applied to flalign environment with automatic pagebreak

Tags: equations, page-breaking, amsmath, rules

I am referring to the `coderule` environment (see [Override \centering to left justify an image](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/6515/override-centering-to-left-justify-an-image/6516#6516)) presented earlier by @TH as answer to the following question: [Override \centering to left justify an image](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/6515/override-centering-to-left-justify-an-image)

I use the defined `coderule` environment for equations (i.e., `flalign`, `amsmath` package). Since my equations are quite long, I allow automatic page breaking for them (`\allowdisplaybreaks[1]`). If I apply the `coderule` around the `flalign`, the equations do not break anymore and leave a lot of unused white space. Is it possible to change the `coderule` environment in such a way that it adapts to the automatic page break?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) Please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-told-i-have-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) that compiles and shows the working of your `coderule` environment. It would make it much easier for others to investigate modifications rather than re-inventing the wheel or gather information from different sources across TeX.SX.

Answer (score 4):

Here is a completely revamped version of the `coderule` environment. This time using the `mdframed` environment from the similarly-named [`mdframed` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/mdframed). The package is loaded with the `framemethod=tikz`, thinking that you're compiling your document using `pdflatex`.

Although `mdframed` produces a framed environment, we set the top, bottom and right margins and lines to `0pt`, and adjust only the left margin specifications. `mdframed` naturally breaks across a page without problem, thereby providing the required functionality by default.

In the following minimal example, the `coderule` environment takes 3 optional arguments:

```
\begin{coderule}[<rule width>][<rule sep>][<rule colour>]
  ...
\end{coderule}
```

The width of the rule is set by the first optional argument `<rule width>` (default is `1em`), while the separation between the rule and the paragraph text is set by the second `<rule sep>` (default is `1em`). Finally, the third optional argument allows you to modify the colour to suit your needs (default is `black`).

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}% http://ctan.org/pkg/lipsum
\usepackage{amsmath}% http://ctan.org/pkg/amsmath
\usepackage[framemethod=tikz]{mdframed}% http://ctan.org/pkg/mdframed
\usepackage{xparse}% http://ctan.org/pkg/xparse
\NewDocumentEnvironment{coderule}{O{1em} O{1em} O{black}}%
  {% \begin{coderule}[<rule width>][<rule sep>][<rule colour>]
    \allowdisplaybreaks[1]%
    \begin{mdframed}%
      [topline=false,rightline=false,bottomline=false,%
       innertopmargin=0pt,innerrightmargin=0pt,innerbottommargin=0pt,%
       skipabove=\parskip,skipbelow=0.3\baselineskip,%
       innerleftmargin=#2,outerlinewidth=#1,linecolor=#3]
  }
  {\end{mdframed}}% \end{coderule}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[1] \bigskip \bigskip \bigskip
\begin{coderule}
  \lipsum[2-4]
  \begin{align}
    f(x) &= ax^2+bx+c \\
    f(x) &= ax^2+bx+c \\
    f(x) &= ax^2+bx+c \\
    f(x) &= ax^2+bx+c
  \end{align}
  \lipsum[5-6]
\end{coderule}
\lipsum[7-8]
\begin{coderule}[2em][1em][orange]
  Here is a short introduction:
  \begin{align}
    f(x) &= ax^2+bx+c \\
    f(x) &= ax^2+bx+c \\
    f(x) &= ax^2+bx+c \\
    f(x) &= ax^2+bx+c \\
    f(x) &= ax^2+bx+c \\
    f(x) &= ax^2+bx+c
  \end{align}
  \lipsum[5-6]
\end{coderule}
\end{document}
```

Of course, the choice of 3 additional arguments may be superfluous. So, that can be removed as well, or the order switched around. Also, the choice of `align` from [`amsmath`](http://ctan.org/pkg/amsmath) is interchangeable with `flalign`.

[`xparse`](http://ctan.org/pkg/xparse) provided the environment definition interface, while [`lipsum`](http://ctan.org/pkg/lipsum) was used for dummy text generation, *Lorem Ipsum* style.

Comment: ! LaTeX Error: Option clash for package mdframed.