# \hrulefill, just vertically

Tags: rules, fill

The command `\hrulefill` fills the rest of the line with a rule. Now, I would like to create a vertical line to the bottom of the page, starting from the last paragraph on that page. Is this possible?

I need the line on the left side, but I am also interested to understand how this can be achieved conceptually, as (to my knowledge) there is no way to know where you are at a certain moment during rendering.

Comment: Along the left margin? The right margin? From the end-point of the paragraph?

Comment: [Something like this](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/96542/4778)?

Comment: It could be remarked that pdfTeX *does* have primitives (`\pdfsavepos`/`\pdflastxpos`/`pdflastypos`) that record, at `\shipout`-time, where a given point is eventually placed on the page (or rendering canvas), and allow you to subsequently retrieve the saved position so that it can, _e.g._, be saved into an auxiliary file and used in the next run.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The command `\hrulefill` doesn't know where it is issued from; it just fills the remaining space on the line in a similar way to what `\hfill` does (actually it is the *same* way).

For `\vrulefill` it's quite similar:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\newcommand{\vrulefill}{\leaders\vrule\vfill}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1]
\vrulefill

\clearpage % <-- not necessary if it's the last page

\end{document}
```

[image]

You can make the rule start from where the last paragraph ends by finishing the paragraph with `\parvrulefill` as in these examples:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\newcommand{\vrulefill}{\leaders\vrule\vfill}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\parvrulefill}{%
  {\abovedisplayskip=\z@\belowdisplayskip=\z@
   \abovedisplayshortskip=\z@\belowdisplayshortskip=\z@
   $$\xdef\vrule@shift{\the\predisplaysize}$$}%
   \par
   \kern-\baselineskip
  \leaders\hbox to\dimexpr\vrule@shift-2em{\hfill\vrule height1pt}\vfill
  \clearpage
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\lipsum*[1]\parvrulefill

\lipsum*[2]\parvrulefill

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: but it would look so much nicer down the centre:-)

Comment: … With the usual _caveat_ as to the use of `\predisplaysize`.  For instance, if the document were being typeset with a non-zero `\lastlinefit`, we would get a bitter surprise.

Comment: @GustavoMezzetti Who's using `\lastlinefit`? `;-)`

Comment: The same ones that might use, for example, `\parfillskip = 0pt plus 1000pt` ;-)

Answer (score 5):

For a line down the centre you can use

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

aaa aaa\\bb bbbb

\leaders\centerline{\vrule height1pt}\vfill

\end{document}
```

Comment: I thought \centerline was a Plain macro that we weren't supposed to use in LaTeX.

Comment: And aren't you setting a bad example with `\\\` in body text?

Comment: @AndrewCashner no of course  my examples are never bad, ask egreg:-)

Comment: @AndrewCashner `\leaders\hbox to \hsize{\hss\vrule height 1pt \hss}\vfill}`