# Indenting text framed by a vertical rule

Tags: margins, framed

I would like to know how to modify the LaTeX based answer to [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/35815/how-to-make-continuous-but-breakable-vertical-rule-along-left-side-of-paragrap) so that the text left margin would be increased by a given amount.  I've tried to change the value of `\leftmargin`, `\evensidemargin`, `\oddsidemargin`, `\textwidth`, etc. to no effect. I can change the text right margin by adjusting `\hsize` ... but that does not help me as I can't find out how to shift the whole thing left. I've also tried to use the `changepage` package but without success.

Comment: Did yout try `\leftskip`?

Comment: I had not. :-(  That seems to work nicely for the text. It does mess up the bottom line but I should be able to figure it out.   Could you change your comment to an answer so that I can accept it as the correct one?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try setting `\leftskip` (untested).

Comment: That seems to work nicely for the text. It does mess up the bottom line but I was able to figure out how to deal with it.