# How to make a text environment

Tags: environments

How can make an environment in which I can write my text and in output, I see it indented with a coloured vertical line?

I want the code be like the following:

```
\begin{textbox}[orange][1cm] % [colour of the line][distance from left margin]
\lipsum[1]
\end{textbox}
```

[image]

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
\lipsum
\end{document}
```

Comment: Clear duplicate: [How to make continuous (but breakable) vertical rule along left side of paragraph?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/35815/5764) Although the answers here are far more acceptable.