# Breakable vertical rules like tcolorbox without TikZ

Tags: page-breaking, boxes, rules, framed

I'm looking for a way to have double vertical lines along the left side of
a paragraph.
It can be done by `framed` package,
but I don't like its spacing (see picture.)
The aim is that `tcolorbox` produces,
but I don't like to use TikZ because
it slows down compilation
(I will use rule frequently.)

I saw
[This question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/35815/151215),
which asked a way to produce breakable vertical rule in Plain TeX,
but the spacing is like one by `framed`.
I also tried `mdframed` package (without TikZ), but it
produced boxes like `framed` and double lines are not supported
(without TikZ or PSTricks.)

So how can it be done without TikZ?

Thanks

### Output

[image: framed vs tcolorbox]
The lines are page frames obtained by `showframe`.

#### Difference *(Added)*

- 'With `framed`' has space between top frame and has no space between bottom.
- 'With `tcolorbox`' has no space between top and has space between bottom.
  In other words, the line ends precisely at the place where the content ends.

### Code

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{framed}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\tcbuselibrary{xparse,skins,breakable}

\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{showframe}

\newenvironment{leftvert}{%
    \def\FrameCommand{%
        \kern 1.75pt \vrule width 1.9pt \kern .7pt \vrule width 1.9pt\hspace{\dimexpr 2em-6.25pt}%
    } \MakeFramed {\advance\hsize-\width \FrameRestore}%
}{\endMakeFramed}

\newtcolorbox{tleftvert}{%
    parbox=false,
    breakable,
    blanker,
    left=2em,
    borderline west={2pt}{3pt}{double},
}

\begin{document}
    \begin{leftvert}
        \lipsum[1-10]
    \end{leftvert}
    \begin{tleftvert}
        \par
        \lipsum[1-10]
    \end{tleftvert}
\end{document}
```

### Another example *(Added)*

**javi_gg1** wrote:

> The way I see it, in both cases the rule begins and ends exactly where the text begins and ends. The difference is that, with `tcolorbox`, both text and rule are aligned to the top of the page frame, while with `framed` both are aligned to the bottom of the page frame.

I give another example to show it's *not true*.

*Edit:* I put this example here so that we can easy to see wrong bottom spacing. So I still have wrong spacing with texts without math.

[image: framed vs tcolorbox]

```
\begin{document}
    \begin{leftvert}
        \lipsum[1-3]
        \newpage
        \begin{equation}
            \begin{split}
                some &= long\\ &= long\\ &= long\\ &= long\\ &= long\\ &= long\\
                     &= long\\ &= long\\ &= long\\ &= long\\ &= long\\ &= long\\
                     &= equation.
            \end{split}
        \end{equation}
    \end{leftvert}
    \newpage
    \begin{tleftvert}
        \par
        \lipsum[1-3]
        \begin{equation}
            \begin{split}
                some &= long\\ &= long\\ &= long\\ &= long\\ &= long\\ &= long\\
                     &= long\\ &= long\\ &= long\\ &= long\\ &= long\\ &= long\\
                     &= equation.
            \end{split}
        \end{equation}
    \end{tleftvert}
\end{document}
```

Comment: You can add the `blankest` option to your boxes and then drawing of frames will omitted and remove the option later on in the final release

Comment: What's the real difference between the framed and the tcolorbox solution? I can't perceive it, as the figures are scaled  differently.

Comment: @Bernard I added an explanation.

Comment: @B.W. As a comment, the way I see it, in both cases the rule begins and ends exactly where the text begins and ends. The difference is that, with `tcolorbox`, *both* text and rule are aligned to the top of the page frame, while with `framed` *both* are aligned to the bottom of the page frame.

Answer (score 6):

The way I see it, in both cases the rule begins and ends exactly where the text begins and ends. The difference is that, with `tcolorbox`, both text and rule are aligned to the top of the page frame, while with `framed` both are aligned to the bottom of the page frame.

When using a `framed` environment, the distance between the baseline of the first line of text and the top of the page can be set by adjusting the value of `\FrameHeightAdjust`. Setting it to a little bit less than `1em` should achieve your desired effect (using exactly `1em` makes it overfill the page and create a blank page at the beginning):

```
\renewcommand{\FrameHeightAdjust}{\dimexpr 1em-0.1pt}
```

[image: frames]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{framed}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\tcbuselibrary{xparse,skins,breakable}

\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{showframe}

\newenvironment{leftvert}{%
    \renewcommand{\FrameHeightAdjust}{\dimexpr 1em-0.1pt}
    \def\FrameCommand{%
        \kern 1.75pt \vrule width 1.9pt \kern .7pt \vrule width 1.9pt\hspace{\dimexpr 2em-6.25pt}%
    } \MakeFramed {\advance\hsize-\width \FrameRestore}%
}{\endMakeFramed}

\newtcolorbox{tleftvert}{%
    parbox=false,
    breakable,
    blanker,
    left=2em,
    borderline west={2pt}{3pt}{double},
}

\begin{document}
    \begin{leftvert}
        \lipsum[1-10]
    \end{leftvert}
    \begin{tleftvert}
        \par
        \lipsum[1-10]
    \end{tleftvert}
\end{document}
```

**Edit:** if you use a `\newpage`command inside a `framed` environment, the rule will extend to the bottom of the page. To prevent this, you can close the `framed` environment, issue the `\newpage`command, and open the `framed` environment again:

```
...
\end{leftvert}
\newpage
\begin{leftvert}
...
```

As for equations, they inherently have some padding above and below, which makes the rule extend longer. If you happen to have an equation at the end of your `framed` environment and you want the rule to end where the equation ends, you can **locally** set `\belowdisplayskip` to `0pt`:

```
{
\setlength{\belowdisplayskip}{0pt}
    \begin{equation}
    ....
    \end{equation}
}
```

Note the enclosing braces that make the change local: you still want to have the padding in other equations.

[image: framed newpage]
[image: framed equation]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\usepackage{framed}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\tcbuselibrary{xparse,skins,breakable}

\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{showframe}

\renewcommand{\FrameHeightAdjust}{\dimexpr 1em-0.1pt}
\newenvironment{leftvert}{%
    \def\FrameCommand{%
        \kern 1.75pt \vrule width 1.9pt depth 0pt \kern .7pt \vrule width 1.9pt depth 0pt\hspace{\dimexpr 2em-6.25pt}%
    } \MakeFramed {\advance\hsize-\width \FrameRestore}%
}{\endMakeFramed}

\newtcolorbox{tleftvert}{%
    parbox=false,
    breakable,
    blanker,
    left=2em,
    borderline west={2pt}{3pt}{double},
}

\begin{document}
    \begin{leftvert}
        \lipsum[1-3]
    \end{leftvert}
    \newpage
    \begin{leftvert}
        {
        \setlength{\belowdisplayskip}{0pt}
        \begin{equation}
        \begin{split}
        some &= long\\ &= long\\ &= long\\ &= long\\ &= long\\ &= long\\
        &= long\\ &= long\\ &= long\\ &= long\\ &= long\\ &= long\\
        &= equation.
        \end{split}
        \end{equation}
    }
    \end{leftvert}
    \newpage
    \begin{tleftvert}
        \par
        \lipsum[1-3]
        \begin{equation}
        \begin{split}
        some &= long\\ &= long\\ &= long\\ &= long\\ &= long\\ &= long\\
        &= long\\ &= long\\ &= long\\ &= long\\ &= long\\ &= long\\
        &= equation.
        \end{split}
        \end{equation}
    \end{tleftvert}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks for fixing top spacing, but bottom spacing is still wrong. See an added example.

Comment: @B.W. See my edit: I added a workaround for the `\newpage` and the equation cases.

Comment: The code I added is just an example which we can easy to see wrong bottom spacing. So I still have wrong spacing with texts without math.